# Regex Suggestion

Tags: regex, string, pdf

I want to parse a PDF file and change them as below. Which regex patterns do I have to use to catch them as Question and Answer seperately?

**Actual Template**

155. Which of the follo.......?

a. Hypertext markup language (HTML)

b. Joint photographic experts group (JPEG)

c. Hypertext preprocessor (PHP)

d. Extensible style language (XSL)

155. c. Hypertext preprocessor (PHP) is used in cre..........

The answer "c" comes after the question number as upwards. I want to change them to the template below.

**Desired Template**

Question: 155

Which of the follo.......?

Answer: C

Explanation: Hypertext preprocessor (PHP) is used in cre..........

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything and gotten any useful results that you have specific questions about? Using regex to modify PDF content is very likely not going to work, even if the text could be seen cleartext in the pdf.

Comment: I'm using a software that converts PDF files to VCE exam files. So I'll use these regexes in the convert process in that software.

Comment: @ÖmerGençay That information in your comment definitively belongs into your question. The question as is makes no sense (as Stefan explained).

Comment: All right forget the PDF part and other details. Take them as plain text. How can I catch a pattern of "155. " and "155. c. " with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work for you, depending on the flavor of regex your software uses.
Find:

```
(\d+)\.\s(.*?)\r\n\r\na\..*?\r\nb\..*?\r\nc\..*?\r\nd\..*?\r\n([abcd])\.\s(.*?)\r\n
```

Replace:

```
Question: $1\r\n\r\n$2\r\n\r\nAnswer: $3\r\n\r\nExplanation: $4
```

All the questions have to be exact same format with 4 answers etc.